# Highcharts display alternate x axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart with multiple y axes and two x axes, i.e. time and distance. I would like to display the chart allowing the user to toggle between the two x axes. I'm struggling with how to define the chart so that it will show the xAxis as distance and have tried setting ordinal to false on the xAxis, using categories, specifying multiple xAxes and can't seem to crack the code. The working solution should produce two graphs as in the linked picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5768Z0sc7d7TFBPVDExU1NXWHc/edit?usp=sharing (as this is my first post, I don't have the reputation to post the image here...)

Here are some simplified code snippets and the related jsFiddle's for your perusal.

```
$('#container').highcharts({

xAxis: {
    categories: [2,4,6,8,12,16,22,24,32,36,44,56], // representing distance
    ordinal: false
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}] });
```

This produces an equally spaced xAxis where each category element takes up one position, i.e. no "stretching" of the data series is introduced. http://jsfiddle.net/robertvizza/LLExL/2141/

```
$('#container').highcharts({

xAxis: {
    ordinal: false
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
},{
    data: [2,4,6,8,12,16,22,24,32,36,44,56], // representing distance
    xAxis: 0
}] });
```

This displays two series over equally spaced xAxis values.(jsFiddle is 2142 - again, first post and therefore can only post 2 links...)

I am hopeful that Highcharts can manage this as I would hate the need to recalculate all the data points to fake out the display across two different xAxes...Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your base xAxis is changing between charts you can try to actually change the chart completely. I created two chartOptions sets and a button to toggle between the two.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    if (set == true) {
    chartMainLoc = new Highcharts.Chart($.extend(true, {}, window.optionsChartDistance));
        set = false;
    } else {
        chartMainLoc = new Highcharts.Chart($.extend(true, {}, window.optionsChartSpeed));
        set = true;
    }
});
```

I am pretty sure there is some one-liner jquery toggle but it is late in the day.
Here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/eyTEp/1/).

Comment: Thanks very much @wergeld. This will certainly help when I get to the toggle code. However, the issue I face precedes this one. I can't seem to create a graph with an x axis that doesn't increment by 1 and scales the series data correctly. See your fiddle modified here http://jsfiddle.net/robertvizza/eyTEp/5/. Note how the speed vs distance graph just swaps one x axis for the other without "stretching" the series. In this example, I would like there to be 56 points on the x axis replacing the 12 from the speed vs seconds graph. Thanks

Comment: @RobertVizza, what you are asking is not entirely clear. Based on your image of your hand-drawn chart this is doing what you wish - both charts have the same xAxis "width". I do not know what you mean by "stretching". Can you put up a fiddle of chart 1 and chart 2 with how you would like them to be?

Comment: Sure thing @wergeld. I figured out how to make the charts look the way I want however I had to alter the data format, which I would rather not do. The first fiddle shows data based on time let's say http://jsfiddle.net/robertvizza/LLExL/2147/. And the second fiddle shows the data based on distance http://jsfiddle.net/robertvizza/LLExL/2148/. This works, but I am getting the different series (time, distance, and the other yAxes) separately from the server and therefore I was hoping to not pay the performance penalty to splice them together as in the fiddles...What would you recommend?

Comment: Well, but you need somehow feed chart with data. If you don't want to do it on a server side, use Javascript and user resources - just calculate values before using them on a chart, general idea: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/2151/

Comment: Thanks Pawel. This would work except that I have 5 y axes and the 2-dimensional array format for series doesn't accommodate. How can I have 5 separate y axes and toggle between one of two x axes?

Comment: @RobertVizza, maybe it is the eggnog, but I am still not sure how these 2 charts you list are different than the presentation of my example. Changing the xAxis scale is simple. But, since both charts are the same physical size there well be differences in "width".

Comment: @wergeld, your example does work except that I have 5 y axes and don't know how to represent them with my 2 x axes given that Highcharts allows for two-dimensional arrays (your fiddle), single series arrays, or objects. Do you have any advice? And thanks for sticking in there with me.

Comment: You are going to need to split out the series into x/y pairs or xAxis categories and yValues where the xAxis categories are the same. Highcharts or any other charting control is not really going to know what to do with multiple axes unless you tell it what to do. From your initial question there are only 3 permutations: time, speed, and distance. If possible put up a jsfiddle with all axes you want and representative data.

Comment: Darn. I was hoping Highcharts could apply an x axis across all y axes used in a chart. Here is the fiddle with real data over 10 seconds. http://jsfiddle.net/robertvizza/LLExL/2166/ So, I'll need to zip each y data series with the selected x axis series then?

Comment: Okay, this is different. Yes, you can have one xAxis with multiple yAxes. You can even have multiple x and y axes. Your original question was to have highcharts change what the xAxis values were (time to distance). Now you want to have one xAxis for time and multiple yAxis? That is absolutely doable.

Comment: Yes, my latest fiddle does show one xAxis (time) with 5 yAxes, but then I need to swap that xAxis for distance, which I don't know how to do. Is that possible?

Comment: My example fiddle will still work in this case. You would just need to create new series of data that is distance based. You then can toggle between the 2 charts. I am not really sure what your other requirements are.

Comment: Thanks again for sticking with me on this. The root issue is that I don't know how to plot 5 yAxes over an xAxis of non-ordinal data, i.e. not time, not category. In this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/robertvizza/LLExL/2166/) there are 5 yAxes and 2 sets of x axis data (tstamp and distanceData). Do you know how to plot the yAxes over the distanceData series as an x axis?

Comment: Question: Are the data points for the various yAxes taken on rigid time intervals such that each `tstamp` point has a data element in each series? If so, is the `distanceData` also taken at the same time point? If so you can do what I put in my original answer. If not then you are going to have to do some kind of transform. You can also take a look at `ordinal`: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal. That may help with spacing.

Comment: It looks like categories don't work with HighStock. And when switching to HighCharts, it appears that setting ordinal to false with numeric category values does not interpret the xAxis value and space them appropriately, i.e. when a distance value is 2.0 miles for 1 minute, I have 60 distance values at 2.0 (1/second) that get plotted while speed (for example) is 0. Instead of those 60 plot points, I need just 1 that represents a distance of 2.0 mi. Thanks for your help wergeld - I'll implement a transform function for the data that normalizes based on distance...